# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2 (from versions: none)

Tags: docker, ldap

i am trying to run docker Version of Taiga Version 6 with ldap support (kaleidos-ventures/taiga-docker) and TuringTux/taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2

When it comes to the custom-back/Dockerfile i have to use local copies of
requirements: django >=1.7, ldap3 >= 0.9.8.4, versiontools >= 1.8

For security reason i cannot go via proxy in dockerfiles using pip.
I copied the required packages to local directories for example:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none -q https://github.com/TuringTux/taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2.git taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext
```

When i do a "build ." i get

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2
```

I use this modified Dockerfilecontent

```
RUN pip3 install .proxy-and-trusted-stuff. --upgrade pip \
&& pip3 install django \
&& pip3 install ldap3 \
&& pip3 install versiontools \
&& pip3 install taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2
```

I cannot find a requirements.txt for this package.
Any ideas how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Using pigar to generate a requirements.txt and include them did not help

Comment: pigar lists taiga and pytest as not found yet!?
The following modules are not found yet:
  taiga referenced from:
    /root/taiga/kaleidos-ventures-taiga-docker/taiga-docker-main/custom-back/taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2/build/lib/taiga_contrib_ldap_auth_ext/apps.py: 22
  ...
  pytest referenced from:
    /root/taiga/kaleidos-ventures-taiga-docker/taiga-docker-main/custom-back/taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2/tests/test_ldap.py: 17

Answer (score 0):

turned out it was a proxy problem.
The error text is misleading.
I had to tell pip, apt, git to use proxy.
Ignore git SSL certs to avoid "server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none"
Command-line parameters did not work as axpected,
so this is the preferred way to go.

```
pip config set global.proxy "my-proxy:my-proxy-port"
pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org" 
git config --global http.proxy http://my-proxy:my-proxy-port
git config --global http.sslVerify false
echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://my-proxy:my-proxy-port";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf

pip install git+https://github.com/TuringTux/taiga-contrib-ldap-auth-ext-2.git
```

The apt-configuration is Debian/Ubuntu specific.
Using the "-vv" parameter for pip was very helpful.

Its now working, thanks for your attention!